# "System.Data" Not available in Visual Studio 2013 Windows 8 Project

Tags: datatable, visual-studio-2013, namespaces, system.data

I have shifted my work to Windows 8 Apps development from VS 2010, I was writing a small piece of code to read from CSV file and I was storing to DataTable, When I copied that code into VS 2013 - Windows App project, For "DataTable" no namespace was found, I tried to add "using System.Data" but that was also unavailable, Then I selected "Add Reference" and also I could not locate the Package.

kindly Somebody do tell if there is any trick to add System.Data Library reference with Windows App project.

Comment: [DataTables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) is *not* listed for Windows Store Apps ("Windows 8 Project"?). I suspect this applies to everything in System.Data.dll (which contains the System.Data namespace and DataTables), and it may not be suitable for any inclusion. Types/methods which are available for Store Apps will have a little 'green briefcase' icon next to them.